# How can I select a unique field sorted by a different field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT DiscountID
FROM (
   SELECT DiscountID, DateCreated
   FROM PayServiceOperations
   WHERE PayServiceTypeID = 2  
   ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
) 
 AS Discount
```

I know that order by not allowe in subquery. But what ways else can I do it?

Comment: You can't! The same DiscountID may belong to different sorted DateCrated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DiscountID, MAX(DateCreated)
FROM PayServiceOperations
WHERE PayServiceTypeID = 2  
GROUP BY DiscountID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curious to know why you have sub query with order by on Date created when you just want to take DISTINCT on DiscountID. Are you looking for this? My two cents !

```
  SELECT DISTINCT DiscountID
  FROM PayServiceOperations
  WHERE PayServiceTypeID = 2 
  ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
```

Comment: it can not work because there is no DateCreated in the selected.